# How to host Laravel 8 project + React Example.js component for a section in the welcome.blade.php on a shared server without installing Node

Tags: php, html, node.js, reactjs, laravel

Have laravel 8 project where i used Laravel Example.js component to inject a script for getting user location current using Html5 navigator.getlocation API for a section in the welcome.blade.php
How do i host this project on a share server without having to install Node?

```
    <div class="bg-holder d-sm-none" style="background-image:url(assets/img/illustrations/hero-bg.png);background-position:right top;background-size:contain;">
    </div>
    <!--/.bg-holder-->
    <!--React component-->
    <div class="container">
      <div id="example"></div>
    </div>
    <!--End of React component-->
  </section>
```

Comment: You just need to copy the compiled js files to the shared sever. If you have SSH access you can do it via `rsync` or `scp` otherwise you can upload via `FTP` transfer

Comment: Donkarnash Do I need the node_modules folder in my production server